# Excel: Dynamic Range excluding data/rows based on blanks in specific column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is there a way to remove from a dynamically generated range full rows based on whether there are blank cells on a specific column within the data that generates that dynamic range?

For example, from the data shown in below table:

[image]

I would need the data in the dynamic range to have only the below highlighted data/rows:

[image]

The newly created dynamic range would be used in a pivot table and I would like to it to group the dates (therefore the need to remove the blank rows within the range).  Please also note that the original list will be updated regularly and would expand (vertically).

Comment: Is there a reason for the blank rows?  Can you filter on Birthday for the blanks and delete those rows?

Comment: there are other columns to the left (and right) of that sample data that I did not include, the entered data cannot be filtered, or removed in the raw data it appears

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$C$9,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$9<>"",ROW($C$2:$C$9),9999999),ROW(A1))-1,COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

Array Formula <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> and drag it in the same row and down

The formula checks if any value in the row is empty (Name or Birthday) to skip the row and look down it
Small will find the smallest row, Row(A1) will change to Row(A2) when drag it down
Column(A1) to copy the first column will become Column(B1) when you drag in the same row
Change B2:B9, C2:C9 and B2:C9 to correspond your Data(last row) and keep $ for fixed references

Comment: Thank you yass for your answer. The issue is that I would like the final table to be in a Defined range format not as an array somewhere else in the spreadsheet.  Also, I would only like to skip the row whenever is data is missing on the birthday column (ie. "5/9/1998 should also be in the result data).  anyway to convert your formula to work in a define range ?

Comment: After having the array you can select it and Define Range (give it a Name)